# Given a sequence of n positive integers, find a subsequence of length k such that the sum over the absolute values of the differences is maximal

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

We are given a sequence of *n* positive integers, which I will denote as *a<sub>0</sub>*, *a<sub>1</sub>*, …, *a<sub>n-1</sub>*. We are also given an integer *k*, and our task is to:

1. find a subsequence of length exactly *k* (denoted as *b<sub>0</sub>*, *b<sub>1</sub>*, …, *b<sub>k-1</sub>*), such that abs(*b<sub>1</sub>* - *b<sub>0</sub>*) + abs(*b<sub>2</sub>* - *b<sub>1</sub>*) + … + abs(*b<sub>k-1</sub>* - *b<sub>k-2</sub>*) is maximal; and
2. output the sum (no need to output the entire subsequence).

I have been trying to solve this using a dynamic programming approach but all my efforts have been futile.

*EDIT:* *k <= n*. The elements in the sequence *b* must appear in the same order as they appear in *a* (otherwise, this would be solved by simply finding max, min, ... or min, max, ...).

**Example input:**

```
n = 10
k = 3
1 9 2 3 6 1 3 2 1 3
```

**Output:**

```
16 (the subsequence is 1 9 1, and abs(9 - 1) + abs(1 - 9) = 8 + 8 = 16)
```

Any help / hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: With k=3, pick some start position and some end position that is higher than the start position.  Now try picking several different middle positions.  Notice anything?

Comment: I do not; nothing that could help me. Sorry.

Comment: @d125q: You may need to think for longer than 11 minutes on a hint like that.

Comment: **1.** What is the relationship between *n* and *k* (*k* <= *n*)? **2.** What is the role of the sequence *a*? The absolutes of the differences appears to be independent from *a*. **3.** How do you define "subsequence of"?

Comment: @stakx: Yes, k <= n. The sequence a is what defines the elements that b can take as well as their ordering. I suppose the task defines a subsequence (maybe a bit incorrectly) such that it preserves the ordering of the initial sequence; that is, the elements in b must appear as they do in a.

Comment: @tmyklebu: I'll see what I can manage until tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @d125q: What I'm getting at is that you can do several cases by hand and then stare at the working and the results for a while.  Not necessarily spend a day meditating.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Yes, that is also what I meant -- I'll take some rest now and try to work some cases out tomorrow and report my results, if any.

Comment: Hmm, the observation I was trying to hint towards would actually be more useful if we were trying to *minimise* the sum...  Anyway it can be useful to explore properties like this.  Further hint: Pick only middle positions that are between the values at the start and end positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. Here's the full code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int abs(int a)
{
    return (a < 0) ? -a : a;
}

int solve(int *numbers, int N, int K)
{
    int **storage = malloc(sizeof(int *) * N);
    int i, j, k;
    int result = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        *(storage + i) = calloc(K, sizeof(int));

    // storage[i][j] keeps the optimal result where j + 1 elements are taken (K = j + 1) with numbers[i] appearing as the last element.

    for (i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
        for (j = 1; j < K; ++j) {
            for (k = j - 1; k < i; ++k) {
                if (storage[i][j] < storage[k][j - 1] + abs(numbers[k] - numbers[i]))
                    storage[i][j] = storage[k][j - 1] + abs(numbers[k] - numbers[i]);

                if (j == K - 1 && result < storage[i][j])
                    result = storage[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        free(*(storage + i));

    free(storage);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int N, K;
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &K);
    int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        scanf("%d", numbers + i);

    printf("%d\n", solve(numbers, N, K));

    return 0;
}
```

The idea is simple (thanks to a friend of mine for hinting me at it). As mentioned in the comment, storage[i][j] keeps the optimal result where j + 1 elements are taken (K = j + 1) with numbers[i] appearing as the last element. Then, we simply try out each element appearing as the last one, taking each possible number of 1, 2, ..., K elements out of all. This solution works in O(k * n^2).

I first tried a 0-1 Knapsack approach where I kept the last element I had taken in each [i][j] index. This solution did not give a correct result in just a single test case, but it worked in O(k * n). I think I can see where it would yield a suboptimal solution, but if anyone is interested, I can post that code, too (it is rather messy though).

The code posted here passed on all test cases (if you can detect some possible errors, feel free to state them).